# Selenium, select a particular span element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to use selenium with python to make some tests. I'm having trouble in selecting an element. this element makes is a part of a drop-down list and it looks like this:

```
<li data-original-index="16">
    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class='text'>Porto</span>">
<li data-original-index="17">
    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class='text'>Santarem</span>">
```

And so on. I want to select the one with the span text "Porto".
I tried the following, but with no success:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()="Porto"]")
```

Any idea on how can I do this?

Comment: Are you getting any error(s)?

Comment: Value Error: No JSON element could be decoded

Comment: Okay, please provide a complete error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Porto");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML you linked it seems like it might be:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@data-normalized-text="<span class='text'>Porto</span>"]")
```

I could be of more help if you posted all the HTML.